# JavaScript find an unknown number in text

Tags: javascript, full-text-search

Okay so I have some different text bits where I need to find some key numbers

Take for instance the following text:

> Ankenævnet har vedtaget at nedsætte den aftalte leje fra 120.000 kr. svarende til 1.363 kr. pr. m² til 92.400 kr. svarende til 1.050 kr. pr. m². Den godkendte leje inkluderer vand. Herudover kan opkræves a conto varmebidrag.

Now the key numbers I need to find here are `1.050` and `1.363`

However, the text may  vary but one thing is certain it is always formatted as such:

```
number kr. pr. m^2
```

So my question is how can I get the numbers out?

**Another example of a text**

> Ejendommen, hvori lejemålet er beliggende, er opført i 1970.
>   Bruttoetagearealet er efter lejekontrakten og BBR 61 m2. Den årlige
>   leje svarer til 1.180 kr. pr. m2 ved 61 m2. Lejer har den indvendige
>   vedligeholdelsespligt. Det lejede er overtaget nyistandsat ved
>   indflytningen og skal afleveres ligeledes nyistandsat ved
>   fraflytningen. Lejemålet ophører med udgangen af marts måned 2013.

Comment: make use of regex?

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/JhSoOv/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this regex:**

```
/[0-9.]{1,} kr. pr. m[\D\d]/g
```

`[0-9.]` it begins digits 0-9 or . and `{1,}` 1 or more times than comes `kr. pr. m` and the last digit `[\D\d]` can be ² or 2
 The /g means it search it in the whole content:

**usage:**

`var str = "Ankenævnet har vedtaget at nedsætte den aftalte leje fra 120.000 kr. svarende til 1.363 kr. pr. m² til 92.400 kr. svarende til 1.050 kr. pr. m². Den godkendte leje inkluderer vand. Herudover kan opkræves a conto varmebidrag.Ejendommen, hvori lejemålet er beliggende, er opført i 1970. Bruttoetagearealet er efter lejekontrakten og BBR 61 m2. Den årlige leje svarer til 1.180 kr. pr. m2 ved 61 m2. Lejer har den indvendige vedligeholdelsespligt. Det lejede er overtaget nyistandsat ved indflytningen og skal afleveres ligeledes nyistandsat ved fraflytningen. Lejemålet ophører med udgangen af marts måned 2013."`
`var regex = /[0-9.]{1,} kr. pr. m[\D\d]/g` 
`var elements = str.match(regex);` 
`console.log(elements)` 
You will get an array with the matching strings

Comment: Try to explain your code when posting

Comment: `{1,}`? Unescaped `.`? Please have a look at that regex again. It's rather poorly written.

Answer (score -1):

Use this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ofsylL/1): [+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+ kr. pr. m²

```
var str = 'Ankenævnet har vedtaget at nedsætte den aftalte leje fra 120.000 kr. svarende til 1.363 kr. pr. m² til 92.400 kr. svarende til 1.050 kr. pr. m². Den godkendte leje inkluderer vand. Herudover kan opkræves a conto varmebidrag.';
var re = /[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+ kr. pr. m²/i;
var match= str.match(re);
```

Answer (score -1):

Regular expression is the easiest way to find string parts by pattern.

I would recommend you use a regular expression builder like: https://regexr.com/3go7t

```js
function findKvadratMeterPriser(tekst) {
  var regularExpression = /(\s|^)(\d)+((\.|,)*(\d)*)* kr\. pr\. m/gi;
  var results = [];
  tekst.replace(regularExpression, function handlePart(value) {
    var findNummer = /(\d)+((\.|,)*(\d)*)*/gi;
    results.push(findNummer.exec(value)[0]);
    return value;
  });
  return results;
}
console.log(findKvadratMeterPriser("Anken\u00E6vnet har vedtaget at neds\u00E6tte den aftalte leje fra 120.000 kr. svarende til 1.363 kr. pr. m\u00B2 til 92.400 kr. svarende til 1.050 kr. pr. m\u00B2. Den godkendte leje inkluderer vand. Herudover kan opkr\u00E6ves a conto varmebidrag."));
console.log(findKvadratMeterPriser("Ejendommen, hvori lejem\u00E5let er beliggende, er opf\u00F8rt i 1970. Bruttoetagearealet er efter lejekontrakten og BBR 61 m2. Den \u00E5rlige leje svarer til 1.180 kr. pr. m2 ved 61 m2. Lejer har den indvendige vedligeholdelsespligt. Det lejede er overtaget nyistandsat ved indflytningen og skal afleveres ligeledes nyistandsat ved fraflytningen. Lejem\u00E5let oph\u00F8rer med udgangen af marts m\u00E5ned 2013."));
```